# Extremely long GC times

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-arguments

We're running JBoss with the following startup arguments but are having problems with long GC times (>5 minutes).

```
-Xms116042m -Xmx116042m -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=95
```

Any suggestions on how we could minimize the GC times?

Note: These are 16 quad core cpu, 128GB linux machines.

GC Logs:

I see many `"CMSbailing out to foreground collection"` messages in the GC logs:

```
130904.206: [GC 130904.206: [ParNew: 240819K->25522K(249216K), 0.2391170 secs] 80798776K->80588205K(118799360K), 0.2395380 secs] [Times: user=2.56 sys=0.01, real=0.24 secs] 
130904.799: [GC 130904.799: [ParNew: 247018K->27648K(249216K), 0.2071170 secs] 80809700K->80601600K(118799360K), 0.2075260 secs] [Times: user=2.61 sys=0.00, real=0.21 secs] 
130905.455: [GC 130905.455: [ParNew: 249216K->27648K(249216K), 0.2808950 secs] 80823168K->80644147K(118799360K), 0.2813140 secs] [Times: user=2.66 sys=0.00, real=0.28 secs] 
130905.765: [Full GC (System) 130905.765: [**CMSbailing out to foreground collection**
131167.602: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 284.753/303.276 secs] [Times: user=909.49 sys=193.05, real=303.23 secs] 
 (concurrent mode interrupted): 80616499K->74658646K(118550144K), 554.7507700 secs] 80651365K->74658646K(118799360K), [CMS Perm : 112620K->112582K(262144K)], 554.7511550 secs] [Times: user=784.15 sys=175.10, real=554.65 secs] 
131461.127: [GC 131461.128: [ParNew: 221568K->27648K(249216K), 0.2620780 secs] 74880214K->74691531K(118799360K), 0.2624960 secs] [Times: user=2.28 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] 
131461.698: [GC 131461.699: [ParNew: 249216K->27647K(249216K), 0.3827130 secs] 74913099K->74807895K(118799360K), 0.3829550 secs] [Times: user=3.52 sys=0.41, real=0.39 secs] 
131462.754: [GC 131462.754: [ParNew: 249215K->27648K(249216K), 0.3022410 secs] 75029463K->74827673K(118799360K), 0.3026050 secs] [Times: user=2.36 sys=0.02, real=0.30 secs] 
131463.789: [GC 131463.790: [ParNew: 249216K->22291K(249216K), 0.2396390 secs] 75049241K->74841234K(118799360K), 0.2400980 secs] [Times: user=2.38 sys=0.06, real=0.24 secs]
```

Comment: Still relevant and good reading - http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-tame-java-gc-pauses.

Comment: ***How much memory*** are you giving this thing??

Comment: We notice gaps in the logs (a few minutes beween log statements) and when using gcviewer there are minute long full gc's going on.

Comment: -Xmx116042m, these are 128GB machines. Are there any options which would make GC times less. I know CMS does pause during mark & remark so would adding CMSParallelRemarkEnabled help?

Comment: 116G heaps?  5 minute gc's?  Where do you work?

Comment: @Ron: maybe it's only young gc that takes 5 minutes?

Comment: Care to share some of the detailed GC logging?

Comment: Note that a long GC is not necessarily a problem.  The twin issues are 1) how long the JVM might be stopped during the synchronous phase, and 2) how much CPU GC is consuming overall.  If these metrics are acceptable then a 5 minute GC is OK.

Comment: Please provide GC log files (running the JVM with -XX:+PrintGCDetails). That way we can see what actually causes the pauses.

Answer (score 1):

Sweeping 116 Gb of stuff for garbage will always take a lot of time, whether you use conc mark, or parallel gc. I always find [this document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) the most helpful source of information for tuning GC. GC tuning will be specific to your app needs and there's no general solution, but many options available.

You might have some more luck with G1GC, because it splits the heap into many small parts and sweeps them independently, but it still might be susceptible to random OOME's.

If tuning GC will fail to yield adequate response times, split the machine into several virtual machines of 16 to 32 Gb of RAM and clusterize it. If it's an EJB app, and you roast your beans correctly, it might not be as painful as it seems.

Comment: It does indeed take a lot of time, however, running CMS without running into concurrent mode failures should not result in long _pauses_. Virtualization _might_ be a solution here, but without knowing more about the use case I would not go as far as saing it _is_ the best solution.

Comment: @KristofferE: yes, `best solution` was an exaggerated statement. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One reason i have observed for full GC to take place is because your young generation is filled up sooner than required which requires the objects to be copied to the old generation. So we can try the following options

1. Set an initial size for your young generation as follows 
    -XX:NewSize=500m -XX:MaxNewSize=500m
2. You can either set a ration for the young generation as a factor of the old generation
    –XX:NewRatio=3

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could set the initial heap to a smaller value. By doing this start up time will be reduced. Since java don't want to allocate a very large heap at the start up. And this will save some time for GC since it usually will run for a relatively smaller heap.

Answer (score 0):

Since you see the message "concurrent mode interrupted" and it seems none of your generations are full at the time of the GC, I think there is an explicit System.gc() call causing your full GCs. Try adding the JVM parameter -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent to make System.gc() calls invoke CMS. Also if you call System.gc() yourself, identify why and remove if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to set the java heap size so close to physical available memory, there is always a fair bit of overhead used beyond what you configure with -Xmx. If you have lots of threads the stacks will require quite a bit together. Have you looked at the output of e.g. "vmstat 1" to see if it's swapping?